# Adding a Custom Class View in XML

Tags: android, xml

I have the following xml source

```
 <View
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:id="@+id/plotViewModel" />
```

if I use View, then I could see my all other views properly on the content.

Since my view will be `oxyplot` (class), then I directly changed it within the `xml`. However, now my content page does put other views properly. However, when I build and run the project, it properly loads. I would like to know is there other way to do it?

```
 <oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:id="@+id/plotViewModel" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the width and height set to something crazy in the code?  (Which we can't see by the way).

Comment: My question is how to have the same functionality without defining custom plotview in xml.